# Change ViewController after animation

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have created this animation for the first screen of the app(I'm not using Launchscreen) but when the animation ends I don't know how to pass to the next view controller. I've tired by segue but nothing :/

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var logoLSMini: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var logoLSMini2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var logoLS: UIImageView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.logoLSMini.alpha = 0.0
        self.logoLSMini2.alpha = 0.0
        self.logoLS.alpha = 0.0
        self.logoLS.frame.origin.y = +100


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut , animations: {
            //FIRST EFFECT

            self.logoLSMini.alpha = 1.0
            self.logoLSMini.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 360)
            self.logoLSMini.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 100, y: 100)
            self.logoLS.alpha = 1.0

        }, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: On the `completion` param of `UIView.animate()`, present your new viewcontroller?

Comment: use the `completion` of `UIView.animate` method. It provides you to finished block, then you can implement the segue or changing view controller in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to perform the segue in the `completion` of `UIView.animate`. Just make sure you substitute whatever identifier you added to your segue in Storyboard for `yourSegue`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut , animations: {
        //FIRST EFFECT
        self.logoLSMini.alpha = 1.0
        self.logoLSMini.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 360)
        self.logoLSMini.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 100, y: 100)
        self.logoLS.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegue", sender: nil)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. It was really simple but didn't work the first time. Maybe something was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the code of moving viewController in the `completionHandler`

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    .....
}, completion: { (finished) in
    if finished {

        //Move to your next controller
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //Your code
        }
    }
})
```